# Problems with Media Player

Tags: android, audio, media-player

Alright so, I am making sound application for android and there is a slight problem.
I made my app to stop playing current sound when I click on another button to play another sound, so they don't play on top of each other.
For first 4 Media Players, it's working good. But there is a problem on 5th and 6th Media player and I can't figure out what's causing it.
When I play Mp6, and I want to play for example Mp2, it pauses it first so I need to double click to play it.
heres my code

```
mp=MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.hekler);
```

ImageButton btn1 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btn1);
btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if (mp.isPlaying()){
        mp.pause();
        mp.seekTo(0);
    }
    if (mp2.isPlaying()){
        mp2.pause();
        mp2.seekTo(0);
    }
    if (mp3.isPlaying()){
        mp3.pause();
        mp3.seekTo(0);
    }
    if (mp4.isPlaying()){
        mp4.pause();
        mp4.seekTo(0);
    }
    if (mp5.isPlaying()){
        mp5.pause();
        mp5.seekTo(0);

    }
    if (mp6.isPlaying()){
        mp6.pause();
        mp6.seekTo(0);

    }
    else{
        mp.start();
    }
    }

});

 mp2=MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.famas);
 ImageButton btn2 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btn2);
 btn2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (mp.isPlaying()){
            mp.pause();
            mp.seekTo(0);
        }
        if (mp3.isPlaying()){
            mp3.pause();
            mp3.seekTo(0);
        }
        if (mp4.isPlaying()){
            mp4.pause();
            mp4.seekTo(0);
        }
        if (mp5.isPlaying()){
            mp5.pause();
            mp5.seekTo(0);

        }
        if (mp6.isPlaying()){
            mp6.pause();
            mp6.seekTo(0);
        }

        else{
            mp2.start();
        }
        }

 });
 mp3=MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.kalas);
 ImageButton btn3 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btn3);
 btn3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (mp3.isPlaying()){
            mp3.pause();
            mp3.seekTo(0);
        }
        if (mp.isPlaying()){
            mp.pause();
            mp.seekTo(0);
        }
        if (mp2.isPlaying()){
            mp2.pause();
            mp2.seekTo(0);
        }

        if (mp4.isPlaying()){
            mp4.pause();
            mp4.seekTo(0);
        }
        if (mp5.isPlaying()){
            mp5.pause();
            mp5.seekTo(0);

        }
        if (mp6.isPlaying()){
            mp6.pause();
            mp6.seekTo(0);
        }

        else{
            mp3.start();
        }   
    }
});
 mp4=MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.emka);
 ImageButton btn4 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btn4);
 btn4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (mp4.isPlaying()){
            mp4.pause();
            mp4.seekTo(0);
        }
        if (mp.isPlaying()){
            mp.pause();
            mp.seekTo(0);
        }
        if (mp2.isPlaying()){
            mp2.pause();
            mp2.seekTo(0);
        }
        if (mp3.isPlaying()){
            mp3.pause();
            mp3.seekTo(0);
        }
        if (mp5.isPlaying()){
            mp5.pause();
            mp5.seekTo(0);

        }
        if (mp6.isPlaying()){
            mp6.pause();
            mp6.seekTo(0);
        }


        else{
            mp4.start();
        }   
    }
});
 mp5=MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.uzi);
 ImageButton btn5 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btn5);
 btn5.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        if (mp.isPlaying()){
            mp.pause();
            mp.seekTo(0);
        }
        if (mp2.isPlaying()){
            mp2.pause();
            mp2.seekTo(0);
        }
        if (mp3.isPlaying()){
            mp3.pause();
            mp3.seekTo(0);
        }
        if (mp4.isPlaying()){
            mp4.pause();
            mp4.seekTo(0);
        }

        if (mp6.isPlaying()){
            mp6.pause();
            mp6.seekTo(0);
        }
        if (mp5.isPlaying()){
            mp5.pause();
            mp5.seekTo(0);
        }

        else{
            mp5.start();
        }   
    }
});
 mp6=MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.sporet); 
 ImageButton btn6 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btn6);
 btn6.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

     @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if (mp.isPlaying()){
                mp.pause();
                mp.seekTo(0);
            }
            if (mp2.isPlaying()){
                mp2.pause();
                mp2.seekTo(0);
            }
            if (mp3.isPlaying()){
                mp3.pause();
                mp3.seekTo(0);
            }

            if (mp4.isPlaying()){
                mp4.pause();
                mp4.seekTo(0);
            }

            if (mp5.isPlaying()){
                mp5.pause();
                mp5.seekTo(0);
            }
            if (mp6.isPlaying()){
                mp6.pause();
                mp6.seekTo(0);
            }

            else{
                mp6.start();
            }   
        }
    });
```

}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This time, the problem is with your *order* of checking the media players and *logical if else conflict*.

Make use of this code in your mp2 part:

```
 mp2=MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.famas);
 ImageButton btn2 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btn2);
 btn2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    if (mp.isPlaying()){
        mp.pause();
        mp.seekTo(0);
    }
    if (mp3.isPlaying()){
        mp3.pause();
        mp3.seekTo(0);
    }
    if (mp4.isPlaying()){
        mp4.pause();
        mp4.seekTo(0);
    }
    if (mp5.isPlaying()){
        mp5.pause();
        mp5.seekTo(0);

    }
    if (mp6.isPlaying()){
        mp6.pause();
        mp6.seekTo(0);
    }
     if (mp2.isPlaying()){ // Put this if branch just before else, likewise for other media players too.
        mp2.pause();
        mp2.seekTo(0);
    } 
    else{
        mp2.start();
    }
    }

});
```

Always check if mp2 is playing or not **just before** the else condition. Likewise for others. That is, only after do you check other players, you should check the current player you are trying to play.

**Let me explain why in detail**:

```
 if (mp6.isPlaying()){
        mp6.pause();
        mp6.seekTo(0);
    }

    else{
        mp2.start();
    }
    }
```

In that portion of **your** code **in mp2 part**, you are checking if *mp6* is playing and stopping it. Since *if* holds good, **else** *won't* execute in that turn. Hence you have to press *again* to make mp2 play. By doing as I said, that is, checking the current player will be matched with the corresponding else condition, and hence your problem will be solved.

**EDIT**: In all six button click events, you have checked if mp6 is playing just before the else part. This is a logical flaw. Before the else, you should have the if of the *corresponding* mediaplayer object.

Comment: Edited my answer with exactly why you are facing the problem with your current code.

Comment: I did like you wrote above, still same error on 6th Mp. When I click on any other button it stops playing it but it doesn't play another MP until I click again. I edited code above

Comment: I don't see the edit in your code. I told you to put if of **mp2** after if of **mp6**, in the **mp2** part of your code.

Comment: I don't think you did that.

Comment: Check my latest edit: I have explained further. That **has** to be the cause of your problem.